# How do I change where psycopg2 looks for a pid file?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to configure a PostgreSQL database. Postgres is installed and running, but the PID file that it creates by default is different from what psycopg2 wants (which is /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432).

When I change /etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf to reflect this file, it fails silently and doesn't create the file. I tried a different file name that did not begin with a dot and it worked.

Is there a way to force Postgres to create this file, or to change the path that psycopg2 looks at to connect?

Thanks.

Comment: What you are describing the is not a PID file, but a Unix domain socket file.  Also, if something fails, show the error message.  If you change a configuration file, say what you changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `unix_socket_directory` in your `postgresql.conf` to force your server to put the socket in `/var/run/postgresql`. I'm not positive where psycopg2 picks up the default path from, I wouldn't be surprised if it were compiled in based on the default.

Comment: That's fine, but it doesn't solve my problem. Postgres is responding to most changes to PID file parameters, it just won't create a file that begins with a dot, which is what psycopg2 looks for.

I suppose I supplied an inappropriate title. It should have been "How can I change the PID file that psycopg2 looks for?" but I believe that is moot because it has to be done by postgres.